# Should we use abuse using the same variable with let because we can?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So let has some really neat scoping rules. As an example from MDN:

```
function letTest() {
  let x = 1;
  if (true) {
    let x = 2;  // different variable
    console.log(x);  // 2
  }
  console.log(x);  // 1
}
```

Wouldn't it be confusing to redeclare the same variable name inside the if-block, or maybe this is just a bad example to point out the scoping rules of `let`?

Are there any good reasons why we should redeclare variable names just because we can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be confusing because a block gives a hint that every block-scoped variable belongs to this block. For ES6-aware developer this should be no more confusing than having a local variable within function scope.

The code above is confusing not because `x` is redeclared but because the code is not self-documenting, `x` variable is redundant, its name tells us nothing on what is going on, *twice*.

ES5 IIFE

```
var result;
...
(() => {
  var filteredResult = result.filter(...);
  ...
})();
```

and ES6 block

```
let result;
...
{
  const filteredResult = result.filter(...);
  ...
}
```

are in the same boat and serve for the same purpose, both of them wouldn't gain anything from variable shadowing.

A frequent case for reusing a variable name is a function parameter, and requires to have access to original variable value, too:

```
(result) => {
  result = result.filter(...);
}
```

On the other hand, having block-scoped variables in sibling blocks may have more practical sense than having them in nested blocks:

```
if (foo) {
  const request = 'foo';
  ...
}
if (bar) {
  const request = 'bar';
  ...
}
```

Both have full control over their block-scoped variables, a `ReferenceError` will be thrown if one of variable assignments is missing by mistake.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks